# Custom fonts (not used in storyboard) won't be bundled in iOS App (Xcode 8.2.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I want to use 3 custom fonts in iOS application.
**But some fonts used only in code, seems to won't bundle in application.**

I imitate this article ["Common Mistakes With Adding Custom Fonts to Your iOS App
"](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/), but only 1 font was bundled.

The bundled 1 font is specified for an UILabel in a Storyboard.
Other 2 fonts are not used Storyboard & xib files, and only used from swift code.

Is this behavior specifications of Xcode?
Cannot i use fonts in swift code only?

---

#### Xcode project information

- Target OS: iOS 8.4 and above
- Library manager: Cocoapod
- Font file type: TTF